# Django-Python/MySQL: How can I access a field of a table in the database that is not present in a model's field?

Tags: django, django-models

This is what I wanted to do:

I have a table imported from another database. Majority of the columns of one of the tables look something like this: AP1|00:23:69:33:C1:4F and there are a lot of them. I don't think that python will accept them as field names.

I wanted to make an aggregate of them without having to list them as fields in the model. As much as possible I want the aggregation to be triggered from within the Django application, so I don't want to resort to having to create MySQL queries outside the application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to write raw sql, you're going to have to define a model. Since your model fields don't HAVE to be named the same thing as the column they represent, you can give your fields useful names.

```
class LegacyTable(models.Model):
    useful_name = models.IntegerField(db_column="AP1|00:23:69:33:C1:4F")

    class Meta:
        db_table = "LegacyDbTableThatHurtsMyHead"
        managed = False # syncdb does nothing
```

You may as well do this regardless. As soon as you require the use of another column in your legacy database table, just add `another_useful_name` to your model, with the `db_column` set to the column you're interested in.

This has two solid benefits. One, you no longer have to write raw sql. Two, you do not have to define all the fields up front.

The alternative is to define all your fields in raw sql anyway.

Edit:

[Legacy Databases](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/) describes a method for inspecting existing databases, and generating a models.py file from existing schemas. This *may* help you by doing all the heavy lifting (nulls, lengths, types, fields). Then you can modify the definition to suit your needs.

```
python manage.py inspectdb > legacy.py
```

Comment: So there is this too. I really didn't want to use raw sql. But won't this still require me to update my models every time my table is updated only in the database? I'm thinking that the columns of the table may be updated from another external (but legit) source.

Comment: If columns are renamed, you're going to have to rename all the columns in your raw queries anyway. At least this way, there's one definitive source within django. Also, you only need to define the columns you're interested in - not all of them.

Comment: Does a field defined like this inherit the characteristics of the column as defined from the database?

Comment: @Carlo, no it doesn't. You have to declare the type it is for validation purposes, and so django knows what python type to convert the data to.

Comment: But what about the other attributes of the column such as maximum length, if null is allowed, or default values?

Comment: @Carlo, that depends on what you want to do with those fields. If you only want to select, then the others aren't required. maximum_length needs to be defined for a valid charfield, but you can give it a large number. If you want to save/update, then absolutely, you need that as part of the definition. See my edit in my answer for a bit more information.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Django allows you to perform raw sql queries. Without more information about your tables that's about all that I can offer.

**custom query:**

```
def my_custom_sql():
    from django.db import connection, transaction
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # Data modifying operation - commit required
    cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
    transaction.commit_unless_managed()

    # Data retrieval operation - no commit required
    cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    return row
```

**acessing other databases:**

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections['my_db_alias'].cursor()
# Your code here...
transaction.commit_unless_managed(using='my_db_alias')
```